# How do I add id parameters to the url of a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to access URL parameters from a website I'm creating using ReactJS and webpack. I have multiple webpages and one webpage is a universal blog post view page. Instead of having to make multiple pages for each blog post, I want to be able to load the blog post by the blog id. When I do this, however, the page expects another page with the blog_id. For example, if the blog id is "test_blog", the URL would be: https://www.example.com/anotherpage/test_blog.

I know that ReactJS has a Link component that handles navigating to different react pages, but it only seems to work in a single page react application. I'm working on a multiple page react application because of the meta data I want to have on each page that I generate.

Would I have to add JavaScript code to the html page itself to get around it, or is there a ReactJS solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add route definition for sub page

```
<Route path="/subpage/:id">
  <SubPageComponent />
</Route>
```

Now in sub page component:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

export default function SubPageComponent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
}
```

Also, why do you have .html in route, please read the docs of react and any routing library: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

For non react router way:

```
window.location.href.split('/').reverse()[0]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to use the routes in react, but my problem is when I want to add meta data to the html. Twitter and Facebook doesn't run js in order to show the SEO information. That eliminated me from using dynamic meta data in react. So I create separate html pages generated with react components with custom meta for each page. Now I'm having problems getting parameters needed for my html webpage.

Comment: why now then just use vanilla JS ? window.location.href.split('/').reverse()[0] will do

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could do it the same as I did

```
export const fetchData = async (newFetchOffset) => {
// console.log(fetchOffset);
const res = await axios(`https://xoosha.com/ws/1/test.php?offset=${newFetchOffset}`)
return res.data
```

}

the Repository is available at [THIS IS A LINK](https://github.com/Mihankhahp/PinterestModel/blob/main/src/Components/Api/Api.js)